# Questions regarding the review process for my code using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I'm getting ready to move my app that I created (in order to use the Facebook API), the process asks for things such as App Name, icon, etc.  I only created an app in order to use the APIs.  I'm calling the app from my website and the app will not be public facing outside of my website.  What should I put for these questions?  Is this even the correct way to use the APIs to write to a company page?  I created the Facebook app because that's the only way I knew to be able to use the Facebook APIs.  If I don't need an app and can use APIs in some other way can someone please direct me to an example?

What I'm doing is allowing a user on our website to post their Testimonial comments to our Facebook company page's Visitor Posts.  They are presented with the Facebook login dialog and then upon successful login the testimonial is written to the company page and the user is returned to our website.

Comment: Don't submit it for review. Just take it live

Comment: I'd like to, but when I go to move the App live, it goes into an automatic review process

Comment: No it doesn't. Just toggle the switch. If you can't hover over it and it will tell you why

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner, I was pulled off the project and was just now put back on it.  So I did what you said and now I'm seeing this error. The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", type: "OAuthException"  I was researching and people were saying this is because I need the publish_actions permission, which I do request in the Facebook login, but nothing comes up to ask the user if they grant the permission.  Then I read that to use this permission, I need to have the app reviewed.  Which if this is the case, it leads me back to my original question above.

Comment: Then it is because the permission is not approved. If it is not approved you can only ask people that have a role on the app

Comment: So how do I get the permission approved?  Through the review process?  If so, then I go back to my original question which is what do I put in for a bunch of information that doesn't really exist based on the way the code was written.

Comment: Yes you go through the review process. You only need to fill in those things if you submit App Details. So don't submit App Details.